# How to submit form with dynamic spinner data in android?

Tags: android

i get the position of the spinner by on item selected listener.
But my point is that when i click the submit button then how could i got the value of the spinner in do in background process? please help me.as i am new in android domain.need some help.

Answer (score 0):

If spinner is accessible in your asyncTask:

```
    String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem())
```

Otherwise, you will have to pass the resultant of above statement to the asynctask

Answer (score 0):

> i get the position of the spinner by on item selected listener. But my
>   point is that when i click the submit button then how could i got the
>   value of the spinner in do in background process?

=> If I got your point then you want to pass selected item data from spinner to the AsyncTask.

If it is the case then you can pass parameters/arguments to AsyncTask too.

For example:

```
private class ParamAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

    String firstParam = params[0];
    .....
    .....
}
```

and execute this AsyncTask by:

```
new ParamAsyncTask().execute("Hello");
```

Comment: i have 3 spinner .one is dynamic and other two is static.i it possible to pass the 3 value of spinner as a parameter??

Comment: You can pass any values as parameters, i mean single or array.